# Do Google Form Apps Need Any Sort of Locking Functionality?

Tags: email, pdf, google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm writing a Google Forms app to collect application data to a spreadsheet, and to email a pdf with the information included.

The code I wrote already works, but I'm a little concerned that it might require some locking.

Do Google Form Apps need any sort of locking in the `onFormSubmit(e)` code for this?

Nobody will be editing the forms after they are submitted, and no usernames are tied to the forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you do need (script level) locking because a new onFormSubmit can get called while onFormSubmit is executing.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/